# Strange behaviour of GridSearchCV with hidden_layer_sizes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.6, grid-search, dask-ml

`GridSearchCV` (no matter if from `sklearn` or from `dask`) seems to to something strange or wrong with the parameters which leads to the MLPRegressor to ignore the parameter.
I show the behaviour in terms of a minimal working example.
Assume numerical initialized `features` and `values` in my case

```
print(features.shape)
print(values.shape)
(321278, 36)
(321278,)
```

and running the following code

```
from dask_ml.model_selection import GridSearchCV as daskGridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV as skGridSearchCV
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
myparams = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(2, ), (4, )]}
daskgridCV = daskGridSearchCV(estimator=MLPRegressor(), n_jobs=-1, param_grid=myparams)
daskbestfit = daskgridCV.fit(features, values)
skgridCV = skGridSearchCV(estimator=MLPRegressor(), n_jobs=-1, param_grid=myparams,cv=3)
skbestfit = skgridCV.fit(features, values)
display(daskbestfit)
display(skbestfit)
```

results in

```
GridSearchCV(cache_cv=True, cv=None, error_score='raise',
             estimator=MLPRegressor(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001,
                                    batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                                    early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
                                    hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
                                    learning_rate='constant',
                                    learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200,
                                    momentum=0.9, n_iter_no_change=10,
                                    nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5,
                                    random_state=None, shuffle=True,
                                    solver='adam', tol=0.0001,
                                    validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False,
                                    warm_start=False),
             iid=True, n_jobs=-1,
             param_grid={'hidden_layer_sizes': [(2,), (4,)]}, refit=True,
             return_train_score=False, scheduler=None, scoring=None)
GridSearchCV(cv=3, error_score='raise-deprecating',
             estimator=MLPRegressor(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001,
                                    batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                                    early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
                                    hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
                                    learning_rate='constant',
                                    learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200,
                                    momentum=0.9, n_iter_no_change=10,
                                    nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5,
                                    random_state=None, shuffle=True,
                                    solver='adam', tol=0.0001,
                                    validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False,
                                    warm_start=False),
             iid='warn', n_jobs=-1,
             param_grid={'hidden_layer_sizes': [(2,), (4,)]},
             pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score=False,
             scoring=None, verbose=0)
```

thus in both cases the `hidden_layer_sizes` parameter has the value `(100,)` which is not in the grid. Am I doing something wrong, or what is happening here?

python-Version 3.6.9
sklearn-Version 0.21.2
dask_ml-Version 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely normal.
`estimator=MLPRegressor()` creates an instance of [MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) with it's default values, when initializing [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) (**(100,)** is the default value of **hidden_layer_sizes** parameter.)

By fitting [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) with data, it will itterate through each possible combination of hyperparameters from `myparams` for each Fold and picks the best one. You can check the results of cross validation by accessing `skgridCV.cv_results_` .

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to simply add another param in the grid parameters with your desired hidden_layers.

Thanks

here is an example :

```
parameters = {
  'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],
  'solver': ['lbfgs','adam'],
  'tol' : 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 6),
  'verbose' : [True],
  'early_stopping': [True],
  'activation' : ['tanh','logistic'],
  'learning_rate_init': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 6),
  'max_iter': [5000],
  'alpha': (.0001, .0002, .0003, .0004, .00005, .00006), **'hidden_layer_sizes'**:(np.arange(1,2)),
  'random_state':np.arange(1, 4)
}
```